# Insect identification, UK, 07-19

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can anyone identify this insect found in the North East of the United Kingdom, July 2019. About 3-4cm long.

Could this be a wood wasp?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If by "wood wasp" you mean order Hymenoptera, family Siricidae, the answer is yes; as for _which_ wood wasp, I'm on the wrong side of the Atlantic to go deeper (though I know the genus _Sirex_ is among your possibilities).

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a Siricidae and looks like a [Urocerus gigas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urocerus_gigas) (sometimes called Greater horntail), which is also found in the UK.

In the Nordic countries this is one of the more common species of sawflies, and I suspect the same is true for the UK. The picture below and some info on their biology can be found at [species.nbnatlas.org](https://species.nbnatlas.org/species/NBNSYS0000161007):
[image]